# How can we import Flutter App to Unity 3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, cross-platform, flutter

I want to make a cross-platform app that uses 3d models and animation from unity but making good layout and widgets is very difficult in unity. So, can I make designs in Flutter and import that to unity?
 
It seems vice-versa is not possible as OpenGL bindings are not currently supported by flutter.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** you make designs in Flutter and import that to Unity3D. What you want is called embedding flutter in native app (Unity3D). To embed flutter [check this article](https://medium.com/@pargearnold/embedding-flutter-in-existing-android-project-733dccacde12).

So, basically you will have to create a flutter application, convert it into a library, import that library in Unity3D project and call your activity.

To launch your own activity from Unity3D, [check this question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/780406/androidunity-launching-activity-from-unity-activit.html)